# Count specific query occurred in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, redshift

I wanted to count the number queries executed over one day. I have this working version :

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', starttime) AS date,
       COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM stl_query 
WHERE querytxt LIKE 'COPY sensor_%_temp FROM%'
  AND starttime BETWEEN '2017-01-24 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-25 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Better in which sense?  Why aren't you satisfied with it?

Comment: @dezso Maybe their is a better way (using interval, not using date_trunc, better naming GROUP BY column..?). If not then that's cool. I just try improve my SQL. I junior in SQL and don't feel confident.

Answer (score 1):

IMO your query looks good. I have one idea.

Instead of:

```
    AND starttime BETWEEN '2017-01-24 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-25 00:00:00'
```

You can write:

```
    AND starttime::date = '2017-01-24'
```

The double column operator (`::`) converts DateTime type to Date, resulting shorter query.

Comment: The difference between the two is that an index on `starttime` wont work for the second version (and an index on `starttime::date` on the first one).

Comment: @dezso Could you explain why? Thanks

Comment: @BeniMio to keep it simple, those are two different data types, to start with.  And (currently) there is no optimization in the planner to match them (AFAIK).

Comment: If he needs and index, maybe it would make sense to create index with `starttime` converted. Something like: `CREATE INDEX ON stl_query (starttime::date);`